# Can I load images for SSRS rdl file from another report project or another folder within solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, image, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

i have a problem with rendering image on RDL file in reporting services (SQL 2008).

I have embedded, external, database as a method of rendering images.

In fact, I know those three option but...

1. I don't think it's a good idea to use embedded. if I have 200+ that use the same image as a report logo or something then it will be better if all report can use the same link to one image. so when i make change with image, I don't have to modify all of reports in my solution.
2. I couldn't use database as an image source because I couldn't create any table to store the images.
3. It seems that the only choice left is ***external***

the folder structure in solution will be something like below

[image]

So my question is

1. Can we load an images by writing some kind of c# library class to get path of those images in share folder?

or

**2. If i choose to embed image into report3.rdl, can report1.rdl get images from report3.rdl?**

any idea will be welcome. I'm at the dead end now.

please advise me.

Sorry for my poor English and Thank you in advance for your help
vee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put an image on a report, I get 3 options - External, Embedded, or Database. Embedded causes the image to be stored in the RDL file itself.

---

Yes, I was going to post something to the effect, but it is starting to abuse the report server. You could put e.g. logos into their own reports, and then put them on the actual reports as sub reports. This would allow you to share the logos across the reports, but only need to update them once.

Comment: Thx for yr reply. I may use poor english so you don't exactly understand what I want to do to this. I just edited my question. If it is possible, please read it again.

Comment: Can we get image from other report files across the project?

Comment: forgot to update that your idea is working fine. storing image in another report and call it as subreport is the answer...YEZZZZ.